# nodejs send attachments from email as multipart/form-data getting parsed by mailparser

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data

I am trying to parse email contents and send email body along with its attachments. I use [mailparser](http://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/) for parsing email contents and `request` library to send `multipart/form-data` POST requests. However, I am getting

`TypeError: source.on is not a function`

error if email contains any attachments.

**test.js**

```
var simpleParser = require("mailparser").simpleParser;
var request = require('request');

var sendEmail = async (emailContent) => {
    try {
        var parsedEmail = await simpleParser(emailContent);
    } catch(e) {
        return console.error(e);
    }

    var data = {
        'ticketId': parsedEmail.subject.split('Ticket No ')[1],
        'message': parsedEmail.text,
        'msgFrom': 'C',
    };

    var formData = {
        createMessageRequest: JSON.stringify(data),
        attachments: parsedEmail.attachments,
    }

    try {
        request.post({url: 'http://localhost:8085/tickets', formData: formData},
            function callback(err, res, body) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error('upload failed: ', err);
                }

                console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
                return;
            }
        );
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

mailparser's `attachments` attribute contains a buffer with content in its `contents` attribute. So, I tried to only take contents and send them as buffer objects as well but it didn't work out. Here is you can see the attachments definition from [mailparser](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/#attachment-object)

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create a Buffer object from `content` of each attachment. [Attachments](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/#attachment-object) in mailparser has an attribute called content which is a buffer to keep content.

```
    var formData = {
        createMessageRequest: JSON.stringify(data),
        files: []
    }

    if (parsedEmail.attachments) {
        for (ind = 0; ind < parsedEmail.attachments.length; ind++) {
            formData.files.push({
                value: Buffer.from(parsedEmail.attachments[ind].content),
                options: {
                    filename: parsedEmail.attachments[ind].filename,
                    contentType: parsedEmail.attachments[ind].contentType
                }
            });
        }
    }
```